# Filtering XML with XPath based on content of child elements

Tags: c, xml, xpath, libxml2, onvif

I need to filter the response of a SOAP web-service. Since SOAP is based on XML, I am thinking about using libxml2, but I am not able to understand how to write an XPath expression to achieve the desired result.

At the end of the message you'll find an example of the response, where two NotficationMessages are sent, one has a topic `tns1:RuleEngine/LineDetector/Crossed` , the other one has topic `tns1:RuleEngine/CellMotionDetector/Motion` .

I am trying to write the following XPath expressions:

- match any NotficationMessage whose topic is `tns1:RuleEngine/LineDetector/Crossed`
- match any NotficationMessage whose topic is `tns1:RuleEngine//.`
- match any NotficationMessage whose topic is everything but `tns1:RuleEngine//.`

All the examples I found match on attributes, not the content of child elements.

So I'm asking.

1. are this kinds of matching doable with libxml2 or with XPath in general?
2. can you please give me a hint about writing the XPath expressions?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" 
    xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" 
    xmlns:tet="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" 
    xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics"
    xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsa:Action>  http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscription/PullMessagesResponse
      </wsa:Action>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <tet:PullMessagesResponse>
        <tet:CurrentTime>
          2008-10-10T12:24:58
        </tet:CurrentTime>
        <tet:TerminationTime>
          2008-10-10T12:25:58
        </tet:TerminationTime>
        <wsnt:NotificationMessage>
          <wsnt:Topic Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/topicExpression/ConcreteSet">
            tns1:RuleEngine/LineDetector/Crossed
          </wsnt:Topic>
          <wsnt:Message>
            <tt:Message UtcTime="2008-10-10T12:24:57.321Z">
              <tt:Source>
                <tt:SimpleItem Name="VideoSourceConfigurationToken"
                               Value="1"/>
                <tt:SimpleItem Name="VideoAnalyticsConfigurationToken"
                               Value="2"/>
                <tt:SimpleItem Value="MyImportantFence1" Name="Rule"/>
              </tt:Source>
              <tt:Data>
                <tt:SimpleItem Name="ObjectId" Value="15" />
              </tt:Data>
            </tt:Message>
          </wsnt:Message>
        </wsnt:NotificationMessage>
        <wsnt:NotficationMessage>
          <wsnt:Topic Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/topicExpression/ConcreteSet">
           tns1:RuleEngine/CellMotionDetector/Motion
          </wsnt:Topic>
          <wsnt:Message>
            <tt:Message UtcTime= "2010-10-20T12:24:57.628">
              <tt:Source>
               <tt:SimpleItem Name="VideoSourceConfigurationToken" Value="1"/>
               <tt:SimpleItem Name="VideoAnalyticsConfigurationToken" Value="1"/>
               <tt:SimpleItem Name="Rule" Value="MotionInDefinedCells"/>
              </tt:Source>  
              <tt:Data>
               <tt:SimpleItem Name="IsMotion" Value="true"/>
              </tt:Data>
            </tt:Message>
          </wsnt:Message>
        </wsnt:NotficationMessage>
      </tet:PullMessagesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need are basic XPath expressions using [location paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) and [predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates):

1. match any NotficationMessage whose topic is `tns1:RuleEngine/LineDetector/Crossed`

   ```
   //wsnt:NotificationMessage[wsnt:Topic = 'tns1:RuleEngine/LineDetector/Crossed']
   ```
2. match any NotficationMessage whose topic is `tns1:RuleEngine//.`

   ```
   //wsnt:NotificationMessage[wsnt:Topic = 'tns1:RuleEngine//.']
   ```
3. match any NotficationMessage whose topic is everything but `tns1:RuleEngine//.`

   ```
   //wsnt:NotificationMessage[wsnt:Topic != 'tns1:RuleEngine//.']
   ```